# Не изменяется Vector3 в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
private void Update(){
      var x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
      var y = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
      Debug.Log(x);
      Debug.Log(y);
      transform.position.Set(x, y, 0);
      if(angle>2*Math.PI){
          angle = 0;
      }
  }
```

Пытался сделать обычное движение по окружности, но постоянно выдаёт ошибку:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
planet.Update () (at Assets/planet.cs:42)
```

`transform.position.Set()` Заменял на `transform.position = new Vector3()`. Потом пытался менять через `transform.position.x =`

Но всё безрезультатно, варианты из инета(даже из документации Unity) выдают ошибку. Я вероятно рукожоп, посему прошу помочь, как правильно делается движение по окружности?

Comment: Очевидно, `transform` возвращает `null`. Почему - загадка. Только по данному коду это не выяснить.